# Should the tag be : `sharia` or `sharia-law`

Tags: discussion, tag

Many people are not familiar what Islamic law and what it is called. Should we use `sharia` or `sharia-law` to make it more explicit. Or any other option you can think of. We do not need duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synonym linking `sharia-law` to [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) might be no harm.

Answer (score 5):

It should be sharia, we can explain what it is in the tag description.

Answer (score 4):

It should be Sharia, Shria-law makes no sense, law means sharia and sharia means Islamic law.  As Mahmoud Hossam  said we can explain what it is in the tag description.